# Git bash error reading vimrc

Tags: windows, vim, git-bash

**Problem:** `git bash` can't read my `.vimrc` file, giving this error:

```
Error detected while processing /c/Users/Simon/.vimrc:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file D:Dropboxdotfilesvimvimrc.vim
```

My setup is atypical, although not too strange.

I have my `vim` directory and `vimrc.vim` file stored on Dropbox (`D:\Dropbox\dotfiles\vim` and `D:\Dropbox\dotfiles\vim\vimrc.vim`) so I can easily move the config and plugins between machines

In my home directory (`C:\Users\Simon\`) I have created a link to the `vim` directory on Dropbox and my `.vimrc` sources `vimrc.vim` from the Dropbox location (`source D:\Dropbox\dotfiles\vim\vimrc.vim`)

When I run `gvim` and `vim` from the start menu everything gets loaded fine and it all works. It doesn't work when using `git bash` though because it seems to remove the required backslashes from the file path. I assume this will also be a problem when trying to load things like color schemes and plugins, which are stored in the Dropbox `.vim` directory as well.

What is the correct fix for making `git bash` see the slashes in `folder/file` links in Windows?

Comment: how you attached vim to git ?

Comment: Do you pass the `.vimrc` file path to `git bash` as an argument when you start `git bash`, or is it just an auto-loaded run com file? It has to be something to do with escaping the backslashes ie. `\\ ` instead of `\\`

Comment: I dont pass as an argument. I assume when I start vim in bash that it just looks in my home directory for a .vimrc file

Comment: Please share your `.vimrc`, or at least its relevant parts.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis OP included `source D:\Dropbox\dotfiles\vim\vimrc.vim` which shows that OP is using the Windows path directory structure in `.vimrc`. `git bash` changes the directory structure to be more *unix-like* so the source line should read `source /d/Dropbox/dotfiles/vim/vimrc.vim`. At least that's my best guest.

Comment: Is there a difference between using back and forward slashes in windows? The reason I have everything in dropbox is because these files need to be usable on osx and linux in addition to windows. Which slash should actually be used to ensure compatibility across all platforms?

Comment: @Simon osx and linux are `unix` *based* while Windows is `dos` *based*, `unix` uses the `/` separator while `dos` uses the `\` separator. There isn't a separator that is compatible for both. I wish there was though : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that using the unix directory structure and forward slashes `/` in the source line:

```
source /d/Dropbox/dotfiles/vim/vimrc.vim
```

actually makes the situation worse because it breaks `gvim` as well as `vim` in `bash` and `cmd`. After OP played around with it, it turns out the fix is actually to just replace all backslashes with forward slashes in the original source line:

```
source D:\Dropbox\dotfiles\vim\vimrc.vim (original)

source D:/Dropbox/dotfiles/vim/vimrc.vim (working)
```

And everything seems to be OK now.

Comment: Just tested this out. It actually makes the situation worse because it breaks gvim as well as vim in bash and cmd. After playing around with it it turns out the fix is actually to just replace all backslashes with forward slashes in my original source line and everything seems to be OK now. Happy to accept if you make the edit because you gave me the idea of re-examining the source line

Comment: Oh wow, awesome. Glad I could help in a round about way. I'll make the edit

Comment: @Simon edited my answer, let me know if I got something wrong and should re-edit.